# How to Implement Blackjack Basic Strategy in Easy Way

Tags: c#, blackjack

I'm working on a blackjack game. I want to implement blackjack basic strategy to program in order to help players.

Basic strategy (from [blackjackinstitute.com](http://www.blackjackinstitute.com))

[image: http://www.blackjackinstitute.com/store/images/Basic_Strategy_Chart.jpg]

I can do it with tons of if statements. For example

```
if(dealerHand[0] == 2 && playerTotal == 9){

  MessageBox.Show("Hit")

} 

else if(dealerHand[0] == 2 && playerTotal == 10){

  MessageBox.Show("Double Down")

}
```

Maybe i can use switch case for it. But i'm not sure. How can I implement it in easy way?

Comment: the easiest way is to just stick.

Comment: rather than turn that table into logic, just put the table into a data structure that you can do lookups on.

Comment: actually, unless card counting, the best strategy is to not play.

Comment: I thought you can only "Double Down" when both cards have the same value?

Comment: @Jodrell You're thinking of split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a simple two-dimensional array:

```
var NextPlay[][] rules = new NextPlay[12][99]; // dealer x player
rules[2][5] = NextPlay.Hit;
rules[2][6] = NextPlay.Hit;
// ....
rules[11][99] = NextPlay.Stay;
```

and then you can access it:

```
var nextPlay = rules[dealerHand[0]][playerTotal];
```

*ATTENTION*: I assumed you can save "special hands" with "special values", e.g. two 9 are a "player total" of 99.

More elegant, but more complex would be some kind of lookup-table, e.g. something like:

```
public class Hand
{
    public int DealerCard { get; set; }
    public int? PlayerTotal { get; set; }
    public int? PlayerCard1 { get; set; }
    public int? PlayerCard2 { get; set; }
    public NextPlay Play { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var List<Hand> rules = new List<Hand>();
rules.Add(new Hand() { DealerCard = 2, PlayerTotal = 5, Play = NextPlay.Stay });
// ...
rules.Add(new Hand()
   { DealerCard = 11, PlayerCard1 = 9, PlayerCard2 = 9, Play = NextPlay.Stay });
```

and then look it up:

```
var nextPlay = rules.FirstOrDefault(h => h.DealerCard == dealerHand[0] &&
                   h.PlayerCard1 == playerHand[0] && h.PlayerCard2 == playerHand[1]);
if (nextPlay == null)
{
    nextPlay = rules.FirstOrDefault(h => h.DealerCard == dealerHand[0]
                  && h.PlayerTotal == playerTotal);
}
var play = nextPlay.Play;
```

Comment: Doesn't properly account for hard/soft totals and pairs, doesn't apply rules in proper order.

Answer (score 0):

The compact table you show makes it easy to print, but hides the fact that it's really four independent tables. The critical thing is that you do everything in the right order, which means:

1. Surrender (about 200 bits of info)
2. Pair splits (100 bits of info)
3. Double down (< 200 bits)
4. Hit/stand (< 200 bits)

Each of these is a 2D table where one axis is dealer's upcard, and the other axis is rank in case #2 and hard and soft totals in cases 1, 3 & 4. That's enough for BASIC strategy. If you want to encode a full count-based strategy, you need 3D tables where the other axis is count value.

Insurance is an unrelated side bet.

You can determine what basic strategy is for your game by running simulations, and filling in those tables, in which case you have to do them in the opposite order: first determine the hit/stand for hard 20, hard 19, ... hard 4 (You need the higher number strategies to figure out the lower ones). Then do soft totals 20..12, using the info you already have. Then do the hard double down table, the soft double table, then the pair split table, and finally the surrender table.